# Extracting details from cucumber reports for Github workflow run using Java/Groovy

Tags: java, json, groovy, cucumber, export-to-csv

I'm new to automation and using Java/groovy for scripting for the first time. I'm trying to interact with the cucumber reports generated after the workflow run.

```
def zipFile = new java.util.zip.ZipFile(new File('cucumber-report.zip'))
def zipFileObjects = []
zipFile.entries().each {
zipFileObjects = new JsonSlurper().parseText(zipFile.getInputStream(it).text)
print(zipFileObjects)
```

Managed to access the cucumber reports, unzip them, and convert them to objects.
The test run contains multiple feature runs. How can I store the information into a CSV based on their feature name, run id, and status(passed/failed)?

Any documents that I can refer to learn more about this?

Thanks in advance.